# Accelerometer with Basic Stamp

Tags: microcontroller, accelerometer

I am a physicist and I'm planning to demonstrate some simple classical mechanics experiments to a group of students. I'd wonder to know if there are any schematics and codes available for connecting a Hitachi H48C Tri-Axis accelerometer to a basic stamp. I've chosen these components simply because I'd like the students to do the experiments from the scratch and Basic Stamps look pretty easy to work with. Nevertheless, I couldn't find any schematics on their web pages.

Thanks

Comment: You'd be doing your students a favor by having them learn to use an Arduino rather than a Basic Stamp. They're similar, but the Arduino has a larger, more active community, and it's programmed in C rather than BASIC.

Comment: Looks like good advice from @pingswept. I haven't worked with Arduino yet myself, but it's the talk of the town. Looks like Basic Stamp is a bit passé.

Comment: Arduino sounds great. Especially the fact that we can program it with C! I haven't touched Basic for many years! I was worrying that it would cause more hassle that it should! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The H48C is a module which contains more than just the accelerometer itself to ease interfacing to a microcontroller.
[This document](http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/HitachiH48C3AxisAccelerometer.pdf) shows how to connect it to a Basic Stamp 2, and also gives you a code example for the BS2.